# How to extract the sign of an integer in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, function

I need a function which returns/prints the sign on an integer. So far I came up with this:

```
def extract_sign(integer)
  integer >= 0 ? '+' : '-'
end
```

Is there a built-in Ruby method which does that?

Comment: That looks fine to me, if 0 should be "+". It's not really "extract" though (as you start with a number, of which the sign is just an intrinsic property of the magnitude).

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Here is a simple way to do it:

```
x = -3
"++-"[x <=> 0] # => "-"

x = 0
"++-"[x <=> 0] # => "+"

x = 3
"++-"[x <=> 0] # => "+"
```

or

```
x = -3
"±+-"[x <=> 0] # => "-"

x = 0
"±+-"[x <=> 0] # => "±"

x = 3
"±+-"[x <=> 0] # => "+"
```

Comment: This is one of the more-satisfying ruby expressions I've seen in a long time. I can't say that it also has prosaic transparency, but I think seeing it teaches important things.

Comment: But what if you want "+" for positive, "-" for negative and "" for zero???

Comment: @JHBonarius You'd use `' +-'[x <=> 0].strip` (see https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/String.html#method-i-strip)

Answer (score 20):

I think that it's nonsense not to have a method that just gives -1 or +1. Even BASIC has such a function SGN(n). Why should we have to deal with Strings when it's numbers we want to work with. But's that's just MHO.

```
def sgn(n)
  n <=> 0
end.
```

Comment: Totally agree, even more so since Ruby's numerics feature way more obsolete fun stuff such as `abs2` or `magnitude`.

Answer (score 5):

You could use [`Kernel#sprintf`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Kernel.html#method-i-sprintf) to format numbers:

```
def sign(i)
  sprintf("%+d", i)[0]
end

sign(100)  #=> "+"
sign(-100) #=> "-"
```

Answer (score 3):

```
class Numeric
  def sign
    if self > 0
      '+'
    elsif zero?
      nil
    else
      '-'
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: You could also see if something is equal to its absolute value – but then you would have to pay for that calculation.

Comment: You need the `class` keyword and not the `Class` contant which is the name of the class Class.

Comment: No... I need to check for mobile auto-capitalization at line-starts :)

Answer (score 2):

Ruby doesn't have a built in sign function like Javascript. Here's a thread that explains more
[http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/141216](https://web.archive.org/web/20120618031123/http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/141216)

Your approach looks correct.

Comment: When I clicked the link above, I expected to find a discussion on why Ruby doesn't have a `sign` function, as opposed to JS which does. Instead, the link goes to a discussion on a Ruby forum about how JS doesn't have a sign function. Or rather, didn't at that time, because JS has since added `Math.sign` which returns -1, 0, or 1 depending on the input.

Answer (score 1):

```
def sgn(x)
 [0,1,-1][x<=>0];
end
```

This return 0 if x==0, 1 if x>0 and -1 if x<0 without manipulating strings.

## example:

`sgn(2.0)*2**2`

Comment: `x<=>0` already returns 0, 1 or -1, so the array is redundant.

Comment: with array is more readable, and inform us about result of `x<=>0` without searched it.

Answer (score 0):

I use `n == 0 ? 1 : n.abs / n`, e.g.:

```
def sign(n)
  n == 0 ? 1 : n.abs / n
end

sign(10) # 1
sign(0) # 1
sign(-5) # -1
```

Comment: Shouldn't `sign(0)` return 0 ?