# Prefix number with "+" if it is positive - Ruby / Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am wondering what the conventional Rails way AND Ruby way is to prepend a "+" sybmol to a number if it is positive.

Example:

```
<%= @number #5 %>
```

Should output:

```
+5
```

By default, negative will display properly:

```
<%= @number #-3 %>
```

Outputs:

```
-3
```

I know I could do something like the follwing:

```
<%= (@number > 0)? '+':'' %><%= @number %>
```

But I don't like that. What is a good way to do this in both Ruby & Rails, or for both if it is the same?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20538670/how-to-extract-the-sign-of-an-integer-in-ruby for a good suggestion. There is no standard/recommended way to display sign for an integer in ruby.

Comment: Did you ask [Google](http://zetcode.com/lang/rubytutorial/strings/) before here? :)

Comment: I am sure Stack Overflow would like user to visit them instead of zetcode. :)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Look at the [sprintf method](http://apidock.com/ruby/Kernel/sprintf)

```
sprintf("%+d", 123)
1.9.3-p392 :005 > sprintf("%+d", 123)
=> "+123" 
1.9.3-p392 :008 > sprintf("%+d", -123)
=> "-123"
```

And in the view:-

```
<%= sprintf("%+d", 123) %>
<%= sprintf("%+d", @number) %>
```

If `@number` will be a positive number then a `+` sign will appear or if it is a negative number the a `-` sign will appear in the view.

Comment: This is nice and clean, I like it. So by the looks of it, there are really no default methods in Rails or Ruby for this...

Comment: `sprintf("%+.2f", 0.1234)` to `+0.12` for float.

Comment: sprintf("%+d", 0)
=> "+0"

Comment: There's also the shorter syntactic sugar: `"%+d" % -123`